# Are there best practice guidelines for how to engage with users?

Tags: design-principles

For example, a current project I'm working on is focused on facilitating group activities with the goal of getting users to sign up for the activity. In the image below the idea is to show a potential group of people interested in said activity and the goal of the design is to entice people to sign up to participate in the activity. In the example below (pardon its roughness), what should go in the circle with the question mark?

1. A photo of someone
2. A photo of someone with the caption 'YOU'
3. The word 'YOU'
4. Something else

I apologize in advance if this isn't the right community to ask this in, but I looked over the various stack exchange sites and this seemed like the best option. To make it specific and not opinion-based, are there rules-of-thumb when it comes to how best to engage with a user?

[image]

Comment: Context. This is very opinion-based and I'm not certain even an *effective* opinion could be presented without at least understanding the "activity". You can't sell cars without knowing you are selling cars. What appeals to softball players will be dramatically different that what appeals to shuffleboard players - but both are "activities". You can only attempt to engage users if you know the context of the desired acquisition.

Comment: .. and of course there's the old advertising adage... sex and money sells. Get someone to believe they'll "hookup" or make money.. and you'll pique their interest.

Comment: @Scott That's a fair point. It's difficult to give a specific example because the project is similar to meetup, where the activity could be hundreds of things. I guess I was looking for a general rule-of-thumb, like "People are X% more likely to engage if they are mentioned in the design" or something like that

Comment: I for one have no idea what your diagram is supposed to mean no matter which of those options you choose so maybe you should think through the entire diagram and figure out it's purpose and how you're conveying that purpose

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the post to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Are you conducting a research group - money, vouchers, rewards, merit, insight would usually get people to sign up, not really sure what you are asking still... group activity could be a sport, litter collection, star-gazing - what is this 'activity' please.

Comment: @MarkRead As mentioned above it's a general design that would be used to entice people to sign up for any activity, including any of the ones you mention. For the sake of discussion, we can use the example of making a volleyball group. So, the left, right, and bottom images would be other people who have signed up and I'm trying to figure out if the top image should be another person who has signed up, with the pitch of "join these people", or if I should work in the word "YOU" based on an idea that people imagining themselves as part of a group makes them more likely to join said group.

Comment: Sounds like a marketing silver bullet - does not quite work like that. If a company wanted me to [buy a watch] and all they had to do is show me 4 pictures to make the sale - i think there would be something wrong with me. You have to appeal to your target specifically. Have a look at this http://www.noesismarketing.com/building-a-brand-pyramid/

Comment: This question makes me feel very smart and very dumb at the same time. Not quite sure I get it. Do you come from a the marketing world? Many designers (also me) likes to think that design is a combination of facts and magic. You must be systematic and seek information, but you must also be experimental and lucky.

Comment: @Wolff I am a software engineer who has no design experience trying to make a project look half decent. :D I think maybe my failure to explain this well is that this is for what is essentially a landing page, so it would be the same for any person looking at it, regardless of activity they’re interested in. My hope is that the landing page entices then to explore the site more.

Comment: I get it now. It's a good question, but it's the question every designer tries to answer. How to engage users. I'm afraid it's too broad. Try to be more specific about the target group. Age, location, interests and so on. Get inspired by similar sites. That might give ideas for the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some opinions:

One must see himself connected to persons which are meaningful without explanations. Otherwise this will not catch his attention. You probably cannot use literally meaningful faces, because you cannot get reasonably priced images and known faces often have plenty of not so wanted things in their history or at the endpoint of their history.

But if you find a way to show wealth, fame, health or contentment or all of them in those 3 other images, you are in the mainstream.

There's the main problem left. How to insert the reader into the chain?  Word YOU and maybe a blank silhouette is technically right and it has not the face of another person. Unfortunately it doesn't call the reader watch it again. It's red in 0,1 seconds. One solution is to add more text. I guess it's boring for most people; they are not interested in small prints, no matter if they read at first the big YOU. It must be an image. Let the word you be below the image to avoid obscuring it.

I cannot tell which is interesting enough image. This needs an innovative artist who understands people that you aim. But check if it's possible to print a perfect mirror to the circle.